# Mysql - Database designing

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a mysql database with bunch of tables.3 of my tables (as shown below) are `tb_posts`,`tb_postsmeta` and `tb_postslyric`. I could merge `tb_postlyric` table with `tb_postsmeta` but I didn't because the size of this table, `tb_postslyric`, is much higher than others.

Do you  think is it a good idea to separate these tables or not? Do you think should I merge them? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**I have read how to design good mysql database before, but there was just how to give appropriate type for each field.**

[image: Picture of tables]

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider:
- What is the purpose of the two tables, e.g content, layout, header info, complementary post info like category or rating, etc. If they serve a different purposes then different tables linked by ids.
- Does the postlyric table have entries that would correspond with multiple entries in postmeta or vice versa e.g one postlyric entry to two postmeta entries then different tables linked by ids
- If one table is significantly larger than the other then you could consider better indexing.